# Scrapy splash^ AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Spider'

Tags: python, module, scrapy, python-import, scrapy-splash

I don't know why, but there's been an error recently:

```
File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\splash\project\project\spiders\scrapy.py", line 5, in <module>
    class ScrapySpider(scrapy.Spider):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Spider'
```

My full code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "spide"
        start_urls = [
        many links
        ]
def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
              endpoint='render.html',
              args={'wait': 0.5},
        )

def parse(self, response):
        "my parsed info"
```

What's the problem and how can it be solved?

P.S. I set up ScrapySplash through [this tutorial](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the name of your python file:

```
C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\splash\project\project\spiders\scrapy.py
```

When you run

```
import scrapy
```

Python is trying to import the current file (that you've written your code in) as the scrapy module. To solve this, rename your file to something other than `scrapy.py`. This will mean that when Python tries to `import scrapy`, it will import the `scrapy.py` file in your `site-packages` folder, assuming you've installed scrapy correctly (`pip install scrapy`).